# What are known useful and misleading memes in the DevOps culture?

Tags: culture

After discovering the [Cattle vs Pets](http://cloudscaling.com/blog/cloud-computing/the-history-of-pets-vs-cattle/) and [12factor apps](https://12factor.net/) DevOps memes which now will help me a lot with communication, I ask myself what are other known memes in the DevOps culture?

Side note: best is to establish fact why a meme is a meme e.g. more than 10K Google query results?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but long lists of answers don't really work well on Stack Exchange sites. The question might be better if you narrow the criteria a little bit (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/336144) for the reasons behind lists being discouraged)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Useful memes:

- "**Wall of Confusion**" from https://www.slideshare.net/littleidea/agile-infrastructure-velocity-09
- **C.A.M.S.** from https://blog.chef.io/2010/07/16/what-devops-means-to-me/
- "**10+ deploys per day**" from https://www.slideshare.net/jallspaw/10-deploys-per-day-dev-and-ops-cooperation-at-flickr/ and https://youtu.be/LdOe18KhtT4
- **I.C.E.** from http://radar.oreilly.com/2015/01/devops-keeps-it-cool-with-ice.html
- "**CI Theatre**" from https://www.gocd.org/2017/05/16/its-not-CI-its-CI-theatre.html

There are some horrible memes pushed by vendors worth mentioning.

*WARNING*: **Bad** memes to use for explaining DevOps (traps for young players) -

- "BI-Modal IT" by Gartner - criticised by Jez Humble here: https://continuousdelivery.com/2016/04/the-flaw-at-the-heart-of-bimodal-it/
- "Multi-Speed IT" by Accenture https://www.accenture.com/us-en/insight-calibrating-multi-speed-it - (same as bimodal, but different name because of copyright - asked about here - [What is good and/or bad about Accenture's Multi-speed IT approach to DevOps?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/what-is-good-and-or-bad-about-accentures-multi-speed-it-approach-to-devops)
- "The Three Ways" by Gene Kim https://itrevolution.com/the-three-ways-principles-underpinning-devops/ - the comments on the article include plenty of criticism

Comment: thanks for the 'bad' memes Evgeny, would you share links to preferrably mostly objective and unbiased assessments why these are misleading?

Comment: Since these are memes, they are hugely popular and discusses all over the place. Every Google search for these would bring out a hefty amount of both criticism and vendor pushing. It is quite easy to distinguish, anything that is not written by the vendor - for these memes would be criticism (not praise).

Comment: partly agree, but, Gartner in that particular case is not a vendor? Neither actually Accenture/Kim. "Vendor meme" sounds to me sth to promote specific offer bound to company's IP. Still, there can be misleading memes for sure which I'd rather qualify as "myths".

Comment: I tried my best. But Gartner IS a vendor in my book, when it tries to explain DevOps using their own made-up ideas. As the saying goes - "Everyone who is trying to define DevOps in a couple of words is trying to sell you something".

Comment: what about Blue/Green deployment? https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html

Comment: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3114195/system-management/the-8-fallacies-of-distributed-computing-are-becoming-irrelevant.html

Comment: http://blog.idonethis.com/two-pizza-team/